# getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments() NPE

Tags: android, onactivityresult

I tried to post the Activity's onActivityResult() to its sub-Fragments and got a NPE. I have no idea why the fragment is null.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    for (Fragment fragment : getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments()) {
        if (fragment != null) {
            fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
}
```

**Excpetion**:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v4.app.Fragment.onActivityResult(int, int, android.content.Intent)' on a null object reference

Comment: post full code which contains this for loop

Comment: I know the reason now. Thx all the same.

Comment: `I know the reason now.` - why don't you answer then?

Comment: @VladMatvienko Thx for reminding me. I'll post it later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a method "makeInactive(Fragment f)" in FragmentManager which use "mActive.set(f.mIndex, null);" to set the fragment null. I should have thought it just remove the fragment from the list instead of setting a null to it.